# Immutable types in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to understand the immutable types. I know that string is immutable, as well as anonymouse type, delagates, but how about this ones? Which of these are immutable in C# and why? Could you explain that?
DataSet, Label, DateTime, object, ArrayList

Comment: `DataTime`s are immutable, `object` has an immutable interface although the real type may be mutable. The rest are mutable.

Comment: `ArrayList` is mutable (you can change item in a `ArrayList`: `a[1] = a[0]`)

Comment: nice way to let your assignment be done by others :P

Comment: Here's a very nice explanation of the benefits of immutable objects http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them/

Comment: I recommend Eric Lipperts articles on immutability, starting from part one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `struct` (= value type) and immutable, but the rest (`DataSet, Label, object, ArrayList`) are mutable:

An object of type `DateTime` can't be edited - all methods on it are returning a new `DateTime` object. All the others can be changed.
`object` is a little special, as it can be "anything" and so AFAIK it is not called immutable.

In general "immutable" means that an object can't be changed after it was created. As correctly stated by Tim `struct`s are mutable by default, but are often implemented in an immutable way. Thus said a value type *can* be mutable, but most of the time it's not. See [THIS](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uFJ4jd) little example what happens when you use a mutable value type.

Comment: `object`s are not necessarily mutable: `object o = new object()` is immutable, and you can't mutate through a variable type of `object`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that value-types like `structs` _can_ be mutable although mostly they are not. If a type is mutable depends on the implementation.

Comment: @ChrFin: as you've already said, objects can be anything. But if you create a "blank" object as Lee has done it is immutable because there are no properties or fields to modify. How do you want to modify something that has nothing to change?!

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thanks for your feedback. I am aware of that, but I am still not sure if it is now called "immutable" or "mutable" (or neither)? Maybe `object` as a value is immutable, but as a type it's mutable/neither?

Comment: _"Mutable"_ just means that you can change it without creating a new instance that you have to re-assign. So if a type has fields that you can modify either directly or indirectly via properties or methods it is mutable, otherwise not. So only the constructor is allowed to "change" the class in an immmutable type. You can make your class immutable by not providing public property setters, public fields or public methods which change those fields.